# fill div with 2 colors?

Tags: html, css

given a div that is 500px wide, is there a way to fill the background with 2 different colors using css? I know it can be done with a background image, but just wondering if it can be done with bg color.
eg :
[image]

Comment: Background image repeat-y, or multiple divs, or border, or box-shadow, or...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't set multiple background colors, but you could set something like:

```
div.twocolorish {
    background-color: green;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
}
```

As long as you don't need text to go over the part in red then this would take care of you in one div.

Comment: Adding to this response, you could push text into the red area using overflow:, padding:, left:, etc...

Comment: This is obvious after seeing it but quite fancy :) box-sizing: border-box works well with this if you want a particular width.

Comment: it is definitely the right side ;) so border-right :)

Answer (score 28):

I ended up with this solution using linear gradients:

```css
    .dualcol-test {
        background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, green 80%, red 80%, red 100%);
    }
```

```html
   <div class="dualcol-test"> This div has a green and red background <br><br><br> </div>
```

Comment: i got what am exactly looking

Comment: best and deserving answer

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve 2 colors in 1 div by using pseudo-element **:before**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="twocolordiv"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.twocolordiv  {
position: relative;
z-index: 9;
background: green;
width:500px;
height:100px;
}

.twocolordiv:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
right: 20%;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: red;
}
```

Comment: Wow! This actually works great! And is even better than the standard div-in-div solution - The text isn't cut.

Answer (score 4):

You can use linear-gradient background to do this

```
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, green 50%,red 50%);
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted 
if you want green ontop  ie the colors should be in column instead of row change the `90deg` to `180deg`

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only set one background-color. However, you could split your container into two and set a different backgorund-color for each one.

Answer (score 3):

This question got me thinking about how CSS3 would approach this problem.. and frankly the specification has me confused. That said, a couple of features that are creeping through the cracks: background-size and linear-gradient.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #ji { width: 500px; height: 300px;  
        background: 
        -moz-linear-gradient(green, green) 0px 0px no-repeat,
        -moz-linear-gradient(red, red) 200px 50px no-repeat,
        -moz-linear-gradient(blue, blue) 0px 250px no-repeat,
        -moz-linear-gradient(gray, gray) 300px 125px no-repeat;

        -moz-background-size: 450px 50px, 50px 200px, 250px 250px, 50px 250px;
    }
</style>
<div id="ji">

</div>
```

Give this a go :)

I'm sure there are better approaches to this problem, but it does demonstrate that we'll be afforded greater flexibility with CSS backgrounds (one day).

**Edit:** *Forgot to mention that this will only work in Firefox, though there are Webkit equivalents for linear-gradient and background size*

Answer (score 3):

Using the [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) css attribute allows you to 'fill' a div with the two colours.

```css
.myDiv {
  position: relative;  /*Parent MUST be relative*/
  z-index: 9;
  background: green;
  
  /*Set width/height of the div in 'parent'*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.myDiv:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; /*set 'child' to be absolute*/
  z-index: -1;  /*Make this lower so text appears in front*/
  
  
  
  /*You can choose to align it left, right, top or bottom here*/
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 60%;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">this is my div with multiple colours. It work's with text too!</div>
```

An easily edited sample can be seen [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/37m4vw68/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Using `background-image` / `repeat-y` is the easiest solution - however, maybe you want to change colours or widths or something with Javascript.

Here's a way to do this which allows text everywhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/WQ8CG/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"><div class="offset">text</div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    background: #ccc;
    border-right: 40px solid #aaa
}
.offset {
    margin-right: -40px;
    zoom: 1; /* to fix IE7 and IE6 */
    position: relative /* to fix IE6 */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Better late then never. Thought this might help:

The htmls

```
<div id="content"> 
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

The csss

```
#content { background-color: #F1EBD9; }
#left { float: left; width: 14em; }
#right { margin-left: 14em; background-color: #FFF; }
```

You can view this @ http://alexandergutierrez.info/stretch-background-color-in-a-two-col-layout

Comment: I was looking for the solution so long... works great on every browser, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could you inset box shadow, and change the shadow to whatever colour you required.

**CSS**

```
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 50px 0px 0px 0px rgba(156, 244, 255, 1);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 50px 0px 0px 0px rgba(156, 244, 255, 1);
box-shadow:         inset 50px 0px 0px 0px rgba(156, 244, 255, 1);
```