# creating a dynamic vertical percentage bar using css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, progress-bar

I am trying to create a percentage bar in my ASP.net MVC to visually display some of the model's data.

I have successfully created the javascript part (albeit in a long winded way). However, I am having a slight issue with the 'visual display', as instead of placing the 'green section' within the div, instead it extends outside of it

(please see this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t3r8oxu/1/) for better understanding).

The actual variables come from the Model (which works! :P), and so will not always be `64%` (this value is represented by the `width`, which I believe *is* the correct height, it just appears below it (doesn't replace some of the red background).

I would like just a small bit of help/advise on how to make this 'bottom border' appear within the div, instead of extending it.

I think I am using the incorrect style or something, but reading from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5054415/3913686), I can't seem to find an alternative.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Current CSS:

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    border: 5px solid #808080;
    vertical-align:central; 
    text-align:center; 
    background-color: red;
}
```

With Javascript:

```
var percent = 64 //obtained from mode's data
var cap = 100 //obtained from model's data
    percent=(percent/cap)
var width = percent*500 //500 is height of div
alert("width is "+width +" cap is read as "+cap +" % is "+percent);
document.getElementById("myTank").style["border-bottom"]=width +"px solid green";
document.getElementById("myTank").innerText = percent +"%";
```

Comment: An [alternative fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t3r8oxu/3/) using a `div` within a `div`

Comment: @Andy I've just looked at jbutler483's answer and it seems to work? I might just have to add a limiting thing to stop it from overflowing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your div is always going to be `500px`, you could use something like:

```
    document.getElementById("myTank").style["border-bottom"]=width +"px solid green";
    document.getElementById("myTank").style["height"]=500-width +"px";
    document.getElementById("myTank").innerText = percent*100 +"%";
```

and here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4cm7zzvj/) of it in action.

Comment: this seems to work happily enough for what i was trying to do, although it might still be improved if there was a way of getting the current height in some way