# Two color table cell background

Tags: html, css

How to make (using only CSS,  without bg image)  html table cell (TD tag) having left half bacground in red color and right half background in green color. I do not want two cells, just one td cell with two-color background defined by CSS.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have used CSS gradients concept. Here the first color starts from 0 and ends at 50% while the second color starts at 51% and ends at 100%. Thus it is possible to assign ratio to each color.

```css
td {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, tomato 50%, lightgray 51%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Two Color Background
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```css
td.halfnhalf {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}
td.halfnhalf > span{
   position:relative;
}

td.halfnhalf:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="halfnhalf"><span>Testing</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you need any further demonstration let me know and I'll set up a jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't see inner text in left half!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you using trick with border or another with pseudoelement described here:
[fill div with 2 colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054415/fill-div-with-2-colors)

or simplier: just make two divs in that TD with different background colors.