# Table Cell two color background diagonally

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Is it possible to have multiple background color for a Table cell like in the image below?

[image: Table Cell Example]

[Two color table cell background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195985/two-color-table-cell-background) seems to do something like what I want but it is not exactly diagonal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both the existing answers are good and this is not at attempt to put them down in any way. This is an improvement on them which can be used if you want responsive design with gradients.

As already mentioned in the other two answers (and seen in the snippet below), the gradient's angles should be modified if the height or width of the `td` changes. This is a drawback when then design has to be responsive but it can be avoided when using the `to [side] [side]` gradient syntax instead of  angled gradients. This syntax can adapt to any change in dimensions.

```
td {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #167891 49.5%, #0D507A 50.5%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

The text inside would need extra positioning to make it appear exactly like in the question.

```css
tr:nth-child(3) td {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #167891 49.5%, #0D507A 50.5%);
  color: #fff;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td {
  background: linear-gradient(18deg, #167891 50%, #0D507A 51%);
  color: #fff;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td {
  background: linear-gradient(33deg, #167891 50%, #0D507A 51%);
  color: #fff;
}

/* Just for demo */

table {
  float: left;
}
table:nth-child(2) td {
  height: 50px;
}
table:nth-child(3) td {
  height: 100px;
}
table:nth-child(4) td {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!-- prefix library included only to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td>Two Color Background</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Two Color Background</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Two Color Background</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr><td>Two Color Background</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Two Color Background</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Two Color Background</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr><td>Two Color Background</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Two Color Background</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Two Color Background</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Henry - just awesome, actually i was to ask the same, as i just encountered this issue. Thank You So So much !

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ: You're welcome pal. Always glad to be of help :)

Comment: a small question, why `49% & 50%`, why not `50% & 51%` ?

Comment: @PaRiMaLRaJ: `50%, 51%` would mean the next color would start slightly away from the edges. I think `49.5% 50.5%` could be more apt. Let me check it in code. (The difference in percentages is to smooth out the jagged edges which tend to come in all browsers with diagonal or angled gradients).

Comment: @Henry - Thanks, understood, gradient seems awesome, will make more time to have better command over CSS gradient.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a rotating degree to the linear-gradient. Note that this is dependent on the height of the `td` element.

```css
td {
  background: rgba(240, 105, 93, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(18deg, #167891 50%, #0D507A 51%);
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Two Color Background
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Independent of height:**

Based on Harry's comment `to top right` will work better since it is independent of the height.

```css
td {
  background: rgba(240, 105, 93, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #167891 50%, #0D507A 51%);
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Two Color Background
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could also use the `to [side] [side]` syntax to maintain the diagonal coloring independent of the dimensions of the `td` :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Harry. You are the best! :)

Answer (score 3):

As in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cxbxt3pr/1/), you just need to set gradient angles like `33deg` to match the corners in my example

```css
td {
    height:100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(33deg, lightblue 50%, navy 51%);
    background: linear-gradient(33deg, lightblue 50%, navy 51%);
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Two Color Background</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```