# Can we dynamically set the range in axis with table operation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

A similar table, where the (x,y) value is dynamic.
when the doc sets its time 7am- 8pm, the start index in the scale should be 7am and end index 8pm, and it can vary / be dynamic.

[image]

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458743/table-cell-two-color-background-diagonally

Comment: Your question possibly not completed, can you complete the question or improve the description